# MySQL basic update query in large-ish MyISAM table too slow

Tags: mysql, performance, sql-update, myisam

`UPDATE SomeTable SET X = null, Y = null` in a (61 million rows, 6.4 GB, MyISAM) table takes about **55 minutes**.  (MySQL 5.7, Windows 10 on i7 laptop, mains cable plugged in, MySQL running at about 30% CPU).  Columns X and Y are **not** part of any index. (I needed to run this query to null some previously entered erroneous data.)

But: `ALTER TABLE SomeTable ADD COLUMN X FLOAT NULL DEFAULT NULL, ADD COLUMN Y FLOAT NULL DEFAULT NULL`, which requires a complete read/write of table plus index takes less than 5 minutes.

What is the problem here?

Table Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `SomeTable` (
   `RecDate` date NOT NULL,
   `STN` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `WBAN` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `Comment` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
   `A` float DEFAULT NULL,
   `B` float DEFAULT NULL,
--  20 nullable FLOATs in total
   `X` float DEFAULT NULL,
   `Y` float DEFAULT NULL,
   KEY `STN_RecDate` (`RecDate`,`STN`)
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Sometimes a complete rewrite of a table can be faster than an update of all rows, if the row size changes.

Comment: The columns updated are fixed length nullable float, so the row size shouldn't be affected by the update.

Comment: Consider ALTER TABLE to remove x and y columns and then ADD the columns back.   You will avoid all the things MySQL does for tracking changes to each row with your query.  Use your TEST environment for testing before doing this in your production Maintenance window.

Comment: @MatthiasOtto Sorry.. I was assuming InnoDB.

Comment: @MatthiasOtto - Did you notice whether the `.MYD` file or `Data_length` changed?  (`FIXED` implies that it would not, but want to double-check.)

Comment: @WilsonHauck - MyISAM simply updates the rows one at a time, in place.  No "tracking changes".  If the rows grew, yes, it would be a mess of changes, including finding free space and/or growing the file size.

Comment: @MatthiasOtto Please post TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE SomeTable;

Comment: Thx for hints & ideas so far.

Comment: @RickJames, no, I haven't checked data length before and after yet, will do with the next UPDATE.

There is one dynamic column `Comment` (see below) but it isn't involved in the update. If MyISAM uses this as the reason to rewrite the whole table for each updated row or block, that would be interesting :-)

Still, I'm not sure whether the resultant file lengths would be different, even with this inefficiency.

Comment: But the one dynamic column may make it more involved for the engine to locate the next record? (So far I've resisted making the `Comment` a fixed length string because this would bloat the table by an estimated 2.4 GB. But it may be worth it just for testing that theory.)

Comment: @WilsonHauck, yes, I could remove and re-add the columns to save time, but I like to get to the bottom of this unexpected bottleneck.  Apart from NULLing I need to do some algorithmic stuff with X and Y (which runs for 4.5 hours).

CREATE TABLE below, somewhat shortened for this forum:

Comment: Sorry, I'm struggling with the intricacies of stackoverflow editing :-(  CREATE TABLE statement is now in the original question above (as no formatting, newlines etc. are enabled in comments).

Comment: @MatthiasOtto - I would expect MyISAM to do this for the `DYNAMIC` rows you have:  Rewrite each row, squeezing out 8 bytes, and turning on 2 bits for NULLs.  The row would be rewritten in place, then the extra 8 bytes would become a short empty space.  Maybe that involves a full 61M disk writes; I don't know.

Comment: @MatthiasOtto Let us know if you come up with a better way than remove and re-add of the two columns.  Thanks

Comment: @RickJames - Sounds unusually inefficient by MyISAM to meddle with a fixed column for the sake of saving a few bytes in the NULL case, but may well be so (and is probably documented somewhere?). Should be easy enough to test, e.g. by timing a trivial non-NULL update, like changing 1s to 0s. Will report back if/when I have some robust benchmark.